# scan in inputs as strings as 2+2 then add the two numbers but iam getting an error while parsing saying that numberformat xception

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num=scan.nextInt();
    String array[]=new String[num];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      array[i]=scan.next();
    }
    int p=0,p1=0;
    String s="";
    String s1="";

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      if(array[i].charAt(i)=='+'){
        s+=array[i].substring(i+1);
        s1+=array[i].substring(0,i);

      }
      int p=Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
      int p1=Integer.parseInt(s1.trim());
       System.out.println(p+p1);

    }  
  }
}
```

Iam getting an error saying number format exception but i tried  everything to fix it but cant find a solution. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException. this is the stack trace i got
any help would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the *precise* error message you are getting, including the stack trace.

Comment: i dont know the stack trace the error is number format exception @JoeC

Comment: If you cannot provide a stack trace, then this question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: pls bro @JoeC help

Comment: I can't help you without a stack trace.

Comment: whats stack trace @JoeC

Comment: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score -1):

try doing

```
    s1+=array[i].substring(0,i-1);
```

because at index 'i' you have '+'

Edit:

You are reading an integer input here:

```
    int num=scan.nextInt();
```

and then you are converting that integer into a string. Try reading a string directly like:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in); 
    String input = scanner. nextLine();
```

and then parse the input

Comment: The `endIndex` is exclusive, meaning that `substring(0,i)` will not include `i`.

Comment: still giving me the same error of number format exception@JoeC

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException. this is the stack trace i got

Comment: any way of fixing this ?@JoeC

Comment: the integer iam reading in is the array size im only converting the string array elements to an int

Comment: @brazil Don't put stack traces in a comment.  You need to [edit] your question.

Comment: @MariaNiaz Given that your answer is incorrect, I suggest that you delete it before it attracts more downvotes.

Comment: there i edited it but i know this is wrong that is y im asking where its wrong @JoeC

Answer (score -1):

if i understand your question well, this should help adding two numbers like "2+2" 
By splitting your string data "a+b" into two (a and b), then parsing each of the
values a and b into integers making sure to  to catch a NumberFormatException in case of a string instead of an integer etc..

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    try{
       String[] splitdata = array[i].split("\\+"); //splitting the data 
       s=splitdata[0];  // getting the first operand
       s1=splitdata[1]; //getting the second operand
       int p=Integer.parseInt(s); //parsing the first operand
       int p1=Integer.parseInt(s1); //parsing the second operand 
       System.out.println(p+p1); //adding
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        // in case of wrong number format or array index exceeded
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
}
```

Test here: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/oQZ

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class Main {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num=scan.nextInt();
        String array[]=new String[num];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          array[i]=scan.next();
        }

        String s="";
        String s1="";

        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<array[j].length();i++){
                if(array[j].charAt(i)=='+'){
                   s +=array[j].substring(0, i);
                  s1 +=array[j].substring(i+1);

                }

          }



          int p=Integer.parseInt(s);
          int p1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
          System.out.println(p+p1);

        } 

      }
    }
```

Try this

Comment: y nested loop it?

Comment: To get your answer without errors. Just try to understand the code. Then you will get the point.

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.